# Sample time series to equal interval

Tags: r, time-series, data-mining, python, data-preprocessing

I have data with timestamp and associated values. time interval between two consecutive data is not constant. How to standardize the the time series and associated value ?
eg- 
Input data is
Timestamp               value
01-03-2015 00:01:18     450.25
01-03-2015 00:04:19     450
01-03-2015 00:06:42     440.75

I want the output with constant time interval (eg-2 mins), then values should also change.
How to achieve this in R or Python ?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Did I understand all right? - you have a continuous-time process sampled at unequal intervals & want to make predictions for some non-sampled times ("standardize" doesn't seem the right the word for that). Note that on this site answers will focus on methods to do that, not necessarily supplying code to implement those methods in any particular programming language.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking for? Are you asking for help with the code or help with understanding how such a thing can be done?

Comment: Code or logic,anything will help. Tried with na.spline and na.approx from zoo library in R. But nothing seems to be working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Consider choosing such an interval that at least one observation is guaranteed to be in that interval and then use simple mean of all observation values in that interval.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely clear what the question is asking, but if you want to get the values every two minutes from your 1st value, then conceptually you can

1) create a new time index, spaced every x min (say, every 2min) starting from your first measurement, and then

2) fill in the missing values by linear interpolation.

**Untested** code using `zoo` in R might look something along these lines:

```
# create new time index 
time.index <- seq(min(index(data)),max(index(data)), by=as.difftime(2,units='mins'))

# combine index with data, and add missing rows to data    
data.merge<- merge(data, time.index, all=T, by="ref" )

# fill in missing data by linear approx
data.fill<- na.approx(data.merge, x=data.merge$time.index)
```